# spring property howto escape special characters in sql?

Tags: java, sql, xml, spring

I got this property in my spring configuration of my dao project:

```
<property name="LBQC">
            <value>
                SELECT u.name, u.cq
                FROM user u
                WHERE u.cq <> 0 ORDER BY u.cq DESC;
        </value>
        </property>
```

Unfortunality I have a problem with that `<>` notation.
It leads to `The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.`
I am not familiar with `xml`. How can I escape those kind of characters?

Thanks for your help.

Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `!=` instead of `<>` in your query to have the same result

```
SELECT u.name, u.cq
FROM user u
WHERE u.cq != 0 
ORDER BY u.cq DESC;
```

Comment: yapp works perfect. Thanks a lot. I will accept in 12 minutes :)

Comment: Note that this only works for this particular problem.  For other uses of `<`, `>` or `&` you need a different solution.

Comment: @StephenC This is meant to answer OP problem and not for general purpose

Comment: @Fabio - While your answer solves his problem, it does not answer his question.  Which is *"how can I escape those kind of characters?"*, and *"howto escape special characters in sql?"*.

Comment: @StephenC i didn't downplay, i'm sorry if i meant so. I just gave op a solution for his actual problem, of course it was not for general purpose, i don't see the point in downvoting, actually this solved his issue.

Comment: @Fabio - The point of downvoting is to indicate that I think this is a poor Answer, and that readers should look at the other one ... because it is objectively better, and more like to solve >>their<< problems.  This is how the SO voting system is supposed to work ...

Comment: @StephenC ok I see your point, anyway i'm sorry, i didn't mean to offend you in any way

Answer (score 2):

replace it with `&lt;&gt;` or encapsulate the entire query in CDATA